# PHP Search Function [MySqli]

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working on a Search Feature but I can't seem to get it working. I'm stuck with this error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\search.php on line 49

This is my PHP code, where the error should be found:

```
<?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%') OR (`content` LIKE '%".$search_term."%')" or die(mysqli_error($conn)));
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                       while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="td-thumbnail"><div class="thumbnail-div"></div></td>
                            <td class="td-date"><?=$row->date_created;?></td>
                            <td class="td-title"><a href="article.php?id=<?=$row->id;?>" class="td-title-link"><?=$row->title;?></a></td>
                            <td class="td-comments"><div class="comments-div"><p class="text-in-comment-div">69</p></div></td>
                       </tr>
                <?php    
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'No results for: ' . $search_term;
                    }

                ?>
```

I've been trying several things to fix it, but I can't seem to find a solution.. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show  `$conn` code?

Comment: brackets in queries are for sub queries; remove them. Plus, make sure you are indeed using `mysqli_` to connect with; that's unknown. Edit: yeah, misplaced bracket. Good catch Mario.

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error(` was the right idea. But it masks the SQL string, not the query call. Move one of the `)` after the final `"` string quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you've a misplaced bracket.

```
or die(mysqli_error($conn)));
                           ^ right there
```

which belongs:

```
LIKE '%".$search_term."%')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                           ^ right there
```

Rewrite:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts 
                               WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%') 
                               OR (`content` LIKE '%".$search_term."%')") 

                               or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

However, and as I stated in comments, brackets are used when doing a  [sub query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html), so you can remove those.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts 
                               WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' 
                               OR `content` LIKE '%".$search_term."%'") 

                               or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

---

**Reference(s):**

Subquery

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html